# Infinite Impluse Response (IIR) Function

Tags: c++, function, matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I am trying to design a signal class which includes an IIR filter function. The following is my code:

```
void signal::IIRFilter(vector<double> coefA, vector<double> coefB){
double ** temp;
temp = new double*[_nchannels];
for(int i = 0; i < _nchannels; i++){
    temp[i] = new double[_ninstances];
}
for(int i = 0; i < _nchannels; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < _ninstances; j++){
        temp[i][j] = 0;
    }    
}
for(int i = 0; i < _nchannels; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < _ninstances; j++){
        int sum1 = 0;
        int sum2 = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < coefA.size(); k++){
            if ((j-k) > 0 ){
                sum1 += coefA.at(k)*temp[i][j-k-1];
            }

        }
        for (int m = 0; m < coefB.size(); m++){
            if(j >= m){
                sum2 += coefB.at(m)*_data[i][j-m];  
            }
        }
        temp[i][j] = sum2-sum1;
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < _nchannels; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < _ninstances; j++){
        _data[i][j] = temp[i][j];
    }    
}
}
```

_data contains my original signal, _ninstances is my number of samples, and _nchannels is the number of channels. The function compiles and works but the result I am getting is different from the result given by MATLAB.  I even use the same coefficients given by MATLAB. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong in my function?

Comment: It would be better to use const reference to `coefA` and `coefB` instead of copying the whole vectors

Comment: You forgot to delete `temp` arrays. It would be memory leak

Answer (score 3):

One issue that I can see is that you are declaring `sum1` and `sum2` as integers when they should be double. To avoid this kind of error in the future, you should try configuring your compiler to warn of implicit conversions. In g++, this is accomplished using the -Wconversion flag.